# Can I throw away contents of my Steam Inventory?

Tags: steam

I have a number of items in my Steam inventory that are never going to get used; for example, some AirMech 2 "gifts" that are marked as NO LONGER VALID.  Is there some way to get rid of them so I don't have them cluttering up my inventory?  Obviously I could do a one-sided trade with a friend, but then *they'd* have to deal with it instead, and I don't have any alt accounts.

Comment: Good question; I have one, too, and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.

Comment: ...and not to mention all those coupons

Comment: Ok, I contacted support and posted a [feature request](http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/864980277862771052/), hope that achieves something...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes you can** for certain items - for example, when I look in my Steam inventory at my many copies of Dota 2, I can select one and a "Permanently delete gift..." button appears as per below;

[image]

This option doesn't appear for all items, for example if I select any of the new trading cards they do not have a delete option and the option is not present for the copy of XCOM I have from the Tomb Raider pre-order - in these instances you can gift them to your friends or, if they're marketable, sell them on the Steam market.

In the instance of your "No longer valid" gifts, I would suggest contacting Steam support if the "Permanently delete gift..." option is not available for you.

Comment: DassalottaDOTAs

Comment: It's so weird that they supply that button sometimes but not others :/

Answer (score 10):

I forget where I heard about it and I haven't used it myself, but [TrashBot](http://steamcommunity.com/id/trashbot) claims to be happy to take those one-sided trades, so you can use it to dispose of undeletable items. For as long as it's still running, anyway.

Comment: Awesome, I just grabbed a 50% off coupon for Magicka from it. Really nice bot. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can donate your coupons to [Coupon Dumpster](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/coupondumpster) group.

According to the group's overview:

> *What we wish to do with the **Coupon Dumpster** is to make it easier on everyone. By providing the service of collecting, listing and finally giving the coupons away to you, the community.
>
>   Here, you can dump your unwanted coupons on us, and we will in return give those coupons FOR FREE to others who want them.*